# Is valediction in one line at the end of offical letter acceptable?

Tags: writing-style, writing, letter-writing

Is valediction in one line at the end of offical letter acceptable?

For example:

```
Sincerely yours, John Snow
```

Answer (score 2):

... in terms of English Language and Usage?
Yes! That is perfectly comprehensible

Does it match [APA](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjDnpGfwdfKAhXJOD4KHVhQD08QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apastyle.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNFoHHnRHFfJtmK0zc-xIg-eSaYWHw&sig2=uU4j4GFj0D0OwVS0niTjJA), [Chicago](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwih8oevwdfKAhXDNz4KHVPAC08QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chicagomanualofstyle.org%2Ftools_citationguide.html&usg=AFQjCNFBLnAyv1LLXWdk0WKtwC3BXChZ5w&sig2=-ZYCPLr_wO8RRsn34fT6oA&bvm=bv.113034660,d.cWw), or other [fetishistic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fetishism) style guides?
No!

If you expect that you will be judged according to a particular formal code then choose and follow a style guide (and know which one, since they contradict each other).